# When launching gnuplot with the -e switch, the window flashes and disappears

Tags: gnuplot, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xming

When I do this:

```
$ gnuplot
> set term x11
> plot x*x
```

Gnuplot correctly opens a window with the plot and everything works great.

However, when I try this:

```
$ gnuplot -e "set term x11; plot x*x"
```

the window only flashes and disappears immediately.

.

I tried both `gnuplot --persist` and `set term x11 persist` but none of them worked.

I'm running Gnuplot inside Ubuntu on Windows 10 with Xming as the X server.

Answer (score 1):

the `-p` option has to be given first

```
gnuplot -p -e "set term x11; plot x*x"
```

btw, the `-p` option is just a shortcut for `--persist`

Comment: Generally this is the correct answer. But for some reason it doesn't work for me...

Answer (score 0):

Adding `pause -1` to the commands solved the problem for me.

This is the final command:

```
gnuplot -e "set term x11; plot x*x; pause -1"
```